# Add variable method to ES6 class

Tags: class, syntax, ecmascript-6

With an ES6 Class, you can declare methods as follows:

```
class Foo {

  bar() {}

}
```

However, I need to import methods from an external file and load them into the class. Something like this:

```
const barMethod = require('./bar');

class Foo {

  bar: barMethod

}
```

However, this doesn't work. I've looked around a while for the syntax for this and it isn't really mentioned. What is the right way to do this?

---

Is there a way to extend the Class perhaps? Because the Class is so big, I am breaking it out into several files for organizational purposes, but each method needs to be able to refer to the Class with `this`.

Mixins perhaps?

Comment: Beside that I belive that you might need to split the class another way, e.g. some smaller classes encapulating functionailities. It should be possible to just write `Foo.prototype.bar = require('./bar')` but I cant test it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `class` in ES6 still uses the `.prototype` so you can extend a class definition after its declaration, by adding methods to the `.prototype.

Original declaration:

```
class Foo {
  bar() {}
}
```

Add some new methods:

```
Foo.prototype.newBar = someNewMethod;
```

Or, in a more modular way, perhaps you want to just pass `Foo` to each module in it's module constructor and it can just add its methods to `Foo.prototype`.

Or, each module could just define its own class with its own set of methods (all designed to eventually be `Foo` methods and then you could use one master function to import all the sub-definitions and copy all the methods from each of the imported classes to your main `Foo` class prototype to end up with one master class.

Keep in mind that methods are just functions on the prototype object, even when the class is declared with the ES6 `class` syntax.  They can be assigned to other objects with regular Javascript that just operates on properties of an object.

Comment: I actually didn't know this! I thought it was an entirely new implementation than prototype!

Comment: @dthree - The ES6 `class` keyword is just nice syntax for putting things on the prototype.  The underlying implementation is still the same.

Comment: @dthree - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can `.call()` `barMethod` from `Foo` instance `bar` property, optionally setting `this` to `this` : `Foo` instance

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
   barMethod.call(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's an idea. Unfortunately I have to import like 50 functions. Is there anything along the lines of extending the class? Edited question.

Comment: @dthree You will need to compose some form of code. There are several approaches that could be utilized. You could simply create a JavaScript function and return an object with `Foo` set as `this`, or use an array of objects to set properties on `Foo` instance `let foo = Object.assign(new Foo(), ...[{bar:function(){console.log(123, this)}}, {fn:function(){console.log("abc", this)}},]); foo.bar()`